# How to print to the left and right of already printed output

Tags: ksh, printf

I have a command say `printf "%5s1"` and its output is:

```
    1
```

How can I print digit `2` to left and digit `3` to right of already printed `1`. So, the output looks like below:

```
   213
```

So, there is one condition here that `1` is already printed using command `printf "%5s1"`.

I've tried using below command,

```
 printf "%5s1";printf "\r%4s2%1s3\n"
```

but this overwrites the existing output `1` and I get below output.

```
   2 3
```

How can I print a digit right side of already printed digit `1` using `printf` without loosing it assuming that I have to use `printf "%5s1"` first? I'm looking for something like:

```
printf "%5s1";printf "\r%4s2???\n"
```

Comment: What are you asking? Is it me or are others completely lost on this question?

Comment: @slm The way I read it, the OP wants to print a string to the left of another string already printed and another string to the right of the original string. For some reason, the middle string is printed first in a separate statement, which is why the OP is using a carriage return to print to its left.

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks, I started reading about the `\r` and the `tput` and then put 2 and 2 together and realized what he/she was asking.

Comment: @slm its `he` BTW.

Comment: @g4ur4v - sorry, hopefully I didn't offend with that. I wasn't sure and was keeping it generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
left=$(tput cub1) right=$(tput cuf1)
printf %5s1; printf '%s\n' "$left${left}2${right}3"
```

#### Details

From the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html):

```
tput cub1
move left one space

tput cuf1
non-destructive space (move right one space)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply reverse the order you're printing in and print the string you need on the right first:

```
printf "%5s1";printf "3\r%4s2\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, use `\b` to backup:

```
$ printf "%5s1";printf "3\b\b\b2\n"
    213
```

Comment: May be better to use `$(tput cub1)` instead of hardcoding `\b` for those terminals where `\b` is destructive and where cub1 is something else (probably rare nowadays though)